# input type range show range value in input type number in html

Tags: javascript, html, input, numbers, range

How do I change the following code so that I can use it for multiple inputs of number type?

```js
function updateTextInput(val) {
          document.getElementById('textInput').value=val; 
        }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value);">
<input type="text" id="textInput" value="">
```

Answer (score 2):

So. What I'd do - I'd expand the function so it would work with several IDs. Something like that:

```js
function updateTextInput(val, elId) {
          document.getElementById(elId).value=val; 
        }
```

```html
<input type="range" name="rangeInput1" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value, 'textInput1');">
<input type="text" id="textInput1" value="">
<br/>
<input type="range" name="rangeInput2" min="0" max="100" onchange="updateTextInput(this.value, 'textInput2');">
<input type="text" id="textInput2" value="">
```

Comment: Replacing "onchange" event by "onmousemove" event allow to see the selected value in real time.